# How to pivot a pyspark streaming dataframe

Tags: pivot, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming, pyspark

I receive streaming data in pyspark structured streaming and I need to pivot them such that I can have a single row from that data.

The struct of data coming to my cluster is that:

```
{
"version": 1.0.0,
"message": {
   "data": [{
    "name": "name_1", 
    "value": 1.0},
    ...
   {
    "name": "name_2", 
    "value": 2.0}]
 }
}
```

My code is the following:

```
dfStreaming = spark \
  .readStream \
  .format("eventhubs") \
  .options(**optionConf()) \
  .load() \
  .select(explode("message.data").alias("data")) \
  .select(("data.*")) \
```

I get the following result dataframe:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|         Name        |       Value      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        Name_1       |         1.0      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        Name_2       |         2.0      |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

But I need the following structure (it's actually a pivot of the table):

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|        Name_1       |      Name_2      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         1.0         |        2.0       |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

The pivot on streaming dataframe is not permitted, but there should be a solution for that I suppose.

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was adding several aggregation with case when to recreate the row of the dataframe.

```
dfStreaming = spark \
  .readStream \
  .format("eventhubs") \
  .options(**optionConf()) \
  .load() \
  .select(explode("message.data").alias("data")) \
  .select(("data.*")) \
  .selectexpr(["sum(case when Name=Name_of_desired_column then Value else null) as Name_of_desired_column"])
```